# CSS Alternate Rows - some rows hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-tables

I'm trying to style a table so that each row is a different colour (odd/even). I have the following CSS:

```
#woo tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #f0f9ff;
}

#woo tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: white;
}
```

However, some of my rows can be hidden and I'd still like the rows to alternate. How can I adjust the above so it gives the appearance of alternate rows, even if the rows that are next to each others aren't necessarily odd and even?

Comment: I hide the rows with "display: none".

Comment: just a quick though: is really necessary to have thousand of rows? You cannot use pagination ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can employ one of its functions, for example [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), to choose only the elements that are visible. But the key here is a CSS selector `:visible`.

For example (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSL7j/1/)):

```
jQuery('tr:visible:odd').css({'background-color': 'red'});
jQuery('tr:visible:even').css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

Comment: I actually tried this, but as my table grew in size, as its always being added to, this seemed to bring firefox to a standstill, hence why i was looking for a purely CSS 'fix' to see if i could alleviate the JS burden on my page.

Comment: As I said, the key here is CSS selector, but it is probably not working in deprecated browsers, like older IE versions (please test whether it works in browsers you want to support). If pure CSS-only solution does not satisfy you, only one that is left is adding specific classes by JS (probably altering my solution, though).

Answer (score 5):

Since the "missing stripe phenomenon" only occurs if an **odd** number of rows is hidden, you might get away with adding a single invisible **padding row** wherever an odd number of rows is hidden.

```
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3 (hidden)
Padding (hidden)
Row 4
Row 5
```

If this actually is a good solution highly depends on your current code, e.g. how you create the table and how rows are hidden.

But if your tables are huge and large chunks of consecutive rows are hidden, this would perform much better than a Javascript/jQuery solution.

Comment: Simply genius!!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue using a background image for the table that consisted of the two alternate colors. This makes for not-quite-a-full-CSS solution as it involves creating an image, but it should scale very well for tables with thousands of entries.

The background-image in the base64 encoding below is a 1x50 image with the top 25 pixels as one color and the bottom 25 pixels as the alternate color.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAyCAIAAAASmSbdAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3wQbATAssXhCIwAAABl0RVh0Q29tbWVudABDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggR0lNUFeBDhcAAAAYSURBVAjXY/j8/joTAwMDTfGXDzdpbQcATuQF2Ze0VigAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
  
td {
   padding: 2px 4px;
   height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>ANIMAL!!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>Beaker</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Bunsen Honeydew, Ph.D.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>Camilla the Chicken</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>Dr. Julius Strangepork</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Dr. Teeth</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Floyd Pepper</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Gonzo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>Janice</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Miss Piggy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Rizzo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Robin the Frog</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>Sam the Eagle</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>Statler</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>The Swedish Chef</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row;">
            <td>Waldorf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
            <td>Zoot</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is super late, but I ran into this same problem today and came up with a pure CSS solution using an `nth-child` formula. I don't know if it fits your exact scenario, but if every other row is hidden but you still need the visible rows to be alternating colors, this works great. The CSS selector looks like this:

`tr:nth-child(4n - 1) { background-color: grey; }`

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzmnq0n9/) showing it in action.

This makes *every other visible row* grey. For more information on how these formulas work, [this is a great tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/).

Comment: This answer is the best in my case. Some of the rows can become visible, but I do not want them to be included in background colour change, so this works better than the jquery : visible solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: This only works if every 2nd row is hidden, but if you use a filter that causes random rows to be hidden, then this code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @narfie - that is why I stated _if every other row is hidden_, and suggested it might not fit the exact scenario. Not sure a down-vote is deserved but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem, I just spent a while playing with CSS2 and 3 selectors, and I'm not sure we're there yet. Something like this should be possible, but doesn't work:

```
tr td {background-color:white;}
tr td:not([style="display:none"]):nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color:#f0f9ff;
}

<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td style="display:none">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
```

Seems you're stuck with jQuery's `:visible` extension (not native CSS), but if it's running slow, definitely paginate the rows as @Ionut says.

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't work because `nth-of-type` doesn't consider any other selectors, but only the element **type**. (In XML-speak it would be the node name) Perhaps one day we'll have a `nth-of-selector-match` selector :)

Answer (score 1):

This question might be old, but when looking for a solution to that problem I came here and inspired by [Jeff Seifert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29886050/1725482) I used a repeating-linear gradient background image to have a purely css based solution:

```
tbody {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(grey 0 2em, white 2em 4em);
}
tr {
    height: 2em;
}
```

The only thing downside is, that you will have to specify a height for the table row (and put the same value in the gradient definition).

**EDIT**:
This only works if all rows have the same height. Sadly max-height does not work for table rows. I have two half-baked solutions for that:

1. Prevent text from wrapping by applying `tr{white-space: nowrap;}` - Care still has to be taken for non-text elements, overflow could also become an issue
2. Wrap the `<tr>` content with another element like a `<div>` and apply `div{max-height:2em;}` - This requires changes in the HTML and also needs treatment of overflow