# css nth-child(2n+1) repaint css after filtering out list items

Tags: jquery, css, filter, css-selectors, jquery-isotope

I have a list of 20+ items. The background-color changes using the :nth-child(2n+1) selector. (ie. even item black, odd item white). When I click a button to filter out specific items using the jQuery Isotope plugin it adds a .isotope-hidden class to the items I want to filter out, which changes the position of the list item to 0,0 and opacity to 0.

When this happens the remaining items are left with the original black/white background-colors, which are now no longer in order.

Does anyone know a way to "repaint' the css using the :nth-child(2n+1) selector on the items that do not contain the .isotope-hidden class.

I tried

```
#element tr:not(.isotope-hidden):nth-child(2n+1)
```

with no avail.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How 'bout stripped down code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I had the same Problem...
Here's what worked for me : [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220587/css-alternate-rows-some-rows-hidden)

Answer (score 4):

Nth-child can be counterintuitive when working with a filtered selection of a group.

Use .each() to get around its limitations:

```
var count = 1;
$('#element tr:not(.isotope-hidden)').each(function(){
    if ( count++ % 2 == 1 ) $(this).css('background-color','white')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS selectors — in particular, pseudo-classes, and in particular `:not()` and the `:nth-*()` family of pseudo-classes — do not work as "filters"; there's a bit of an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217086/css-selector-involving-pseudo-class-first-child-and-dropcap/5217102#5217102), although it seems a little awkward in retrospect. Here's a better explanation.

Simple selectors in a sequence aren't processed in the order they are written *one by one*; rather, they are a set of conditions that an element must match in order for styles to apply to it, and the element must match all these conditions as they are, *together*. Or instead of calling them *conditions* you could also call them *descriptors*, but I would consider "filters" a misnomer when it comes to CSS selectors.

Your selector means:

> Select this element if and only if it is located within `#element` and it matches all these conditions:
>
> - It is a `tr` element
> - It does not have the class `isotope-hidden`
> - It is the (2n+1)th child of its parent

It does not mean:

> 1. Look inside the contents of `#element`
> 2. Select all `tr` elements
> 3. Filter out elements that do not have the class `isotope-hidden` among these elements
> 4. Apply styles to every (2n+1)th child among these filtered elements

Even if you could "repaint" or reapply styles after filtering them out, it wouldn't work anyway. This is because whether or not an element the `isotope-hidden` class (or even whether or not it's a `tr`!), the `:not(.isotope-hidden)` selector isn't going to change the fact that an element that is `:nth-child(1)` is the first child of its parent in the DOM, an element that is `:nth-child(2)` is the second child of its parent in the DOM, and so on.

If you need sequential filters, you won't be able to do this with a pure CSS selector; you'll have to use [jQuery's filter methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering), which were designed for this very purpose, to add a class to the respective elements which you can then use to apply your styles:

```
$('#element tr').not('.isotope-hidden').filter(':even');
```

As an aside, this can also be rewritten as a single jQuery selector, using its [filter selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors):

```
$('#element tr:not(.isotope-hidden):even');
```

However, despite the similar syntax, there is a *vast* difference between true CSS selectors and jQuery filters, which is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter/10835694#10835694).