# Isotope objects with custom css margins based on child-nth and js

Tags: javascript, css, margin, jquery-isotope, css-selectors

I have been doing simple .isotope gallery and this is how it looks with selected #portfolio-wrap containter in chrome dev tools:

---

I couldn't upload three links so you have to go back here:
-->  [Gallery - check image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQFim.jpg)  <--

---

Every .isotope object (a circle with text) has

```
margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
```

Like on the screen:

--> Check image 2 now <--

<strike>There are four objects in the row. What I want is no margins for left and right side of first and fourth item so that every one is sticking to "walls" of parent body container.</strike> 

Edit:
Every item should have bottom margin of 20px and every item except 1,5,9 or in other words 4n+1 should also have left-margin of 20px. So they will nicely stack. [image](https://www.imgur.com/nusu8n0)

So I have tried with `nth-child`:

```
#portfolio-wrap > div:nth-child(4n+1)  {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

But it makes isotope act buggy as seen below.
The red numbers are consecutive child numbers as they should appear according to code without filtering:

--> Check image 3 now <--

The first and fifth children have their margin applied good. And everything would be well if not two things:

1. After filtering the applied margin is not changing.
2. The position bug, as on last imgur link.

ad. 1
I have found a js solution to one problem and it works partially for me: [Stackoverflow - click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677827/css-nth-child2n1-repaint-css-after-filtering-out-list-items) When I apply the 4n+1 code it doesnt work, whats wrong? (I'm not really any good with js)

```
var x=0;
$('.portfolio-item:not(.isotope-hidden)').each(function(){
     for (x=4*x+1; x<=50; x++ ) { 
        $(this).css('margin','0 0 20px 0') 
     } else {
        $(this).css('margin','0 0 20px 20px')
     }
})
```

ad. 2
I don't know what causes the alignment bug. I thought that could be too much margins destroying wrapper, but it is not the case.

## Update for everybody:

I have fixed my js and it works!:

```
$('.portfolio-item:not(.isotope-hidden)').each(function()) {
        for (x = 1; x <= 50; ++x) { 
        if ((x - 1) % 4 == 0) {
            $(this).css('margin','0 0 20px 0') 
        } else { 
                $(this).css('margin','0 0 20px 20px')  
        } 
    }}
```

Layout bug is still bugging as on image3!

Also js after filtering is not applying new margin... :(

## Update 2:

I have resolved the problem by applying gutterWidth (see isotope manuals) also you not only need apply gutterwidth but also long stack of code from demo of gutterwidth from source. Shame on you isotope documentation.

Comment: Please show your html and css. By the way, are you  really looking forward for a bottom margin of 20 px for the first end every 4th element onwards? Like t this 1,5,9,etc..

Comment: Every item must have bottom margin of 20px, and every item except of 1,5,9 etc has to have left maring of 2px. Like here: http://imgur.com/nusu8n0 I will edit js css because it should be 0 0 20px 0; not 0 0 0 20px;. Its wordpress and it will be hard to show code, so maybe specify what part do you want? :)

Comment: Read my answer below. Your jscript code is not correct. In your question you stated that "Every .isotope object (a circle with text) has  margin: 0 10px 0 10px; "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to target every first and forth child element for each row of 4 elements leaving the first without left margin and the 4th without right margin you should use the following rules
(based on the classes you mentioned in your question....)

```
#portfolio-wrap > div:nth-child(4n+1)  {
    margin-left: 0px;

}
#portfolio-wrap > div:nth-child(4n+4)  {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

**Broken lay-out**

Not sure without taking a look to your code.
But it seams that #5 is floating right , #3 cant find his place and goes down as it is supposed to happen with a floating element. It does not reach the left of the container because it finds place after #1 which is using a bottom margin of 20px.
Lastly #4 finds its place below #3 and it can reach the left side of the container.
So what you see is the expected layout as the Visual formatting model says.

**javascript function**

Take a look there as well. An **else** statement should follow an **if**.

Comment: Every item should have bottom margin of 20px and every item except 1,5,9 or 4n+1 should also have left-margin of 20px. So they will nicely stack. http://imgur.com/nusu8n0. Im really lame at js so no suprise i messed this up. Ill check the floats, thanks!

Comment: Also I cant really show html and css files as i dont own it, its commercial wordpress and some parts of code arent mine. :/